# Is it possible to downgrade an object in objective c to its superclass?

Tags: objective-c, casting, object

If I have an instance of class B which is a subclass of class A, is there a way for me to turn my instance of class B into an instance of class A without explicitly writing code to do it?

I do not mean simply downcasting with the standard c syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be able to do this with the objc runtime (see the `object_setClass(id object, Class cls)` in the Objective-C runtime reference. The more important point, however, is that you almost certainly do not want to do this. If your subclass does not follow the [Liskov Substituion Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), it shouldn't be a subclass (i.e. an inheritance relationship is not appropriate and you should choose some other design). You can always invoke the superclass' method implementations with `[super someMethod]` from within your subclass.